# Converting functions to a Class

Tags: class, cookies, alert

The following code shows an alert if the user is using IE11 and sets a cookie that expires after 24 hours:

```
var cookieExists = document.cookie.indexOf('ie11_cookie') >= 0;

// Function for checking if IE11 or bellow
function isIE() {  
  return window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE|Trident)/);
}

// Function for setting a cookie
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

// If the user is using IE11 and no cookie exist, show the alert and set a cookie
if (isIE() && !cookieExists) {
  window.alert("Your browser is outdated!");
  // Setting a cookie with an expiry date of 1 day
  createCookie('myCookie', 'ie11_cookie', 1);
}
```

The script works but now I'm trying to convert it to a class. 
I've tried this:

```
var cookieExists = document.cookie.indexOf('ie11_cookie') >= 0;

class ieAlert {
  // Method for checking if IE11 or bellow
  isIE() {  
    return window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE|Trident)/);
  }
  // Method for setting a cookie
  createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
  }
}
// If the user is using IE11 and no cookie exist, show the alert and set a cookie
if (ieAlert.isIE() && !cookieExists) {
  window.alert("Your browser is outdated!");
  // Setting a cookie with an expiry date on 1 day
  createCookie('myCookie', 'ie11_cookie', 1);
}

module.exports = ieAlert;
```

But if I run the code, I get the following error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: ieAlert.isIE is not a function

I also don't want to use any ES6 syntax as the script should work in IE11 and I'm not using Babel.

What am I doing wrong? What would be the right solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to call a function on an instance of the class, but on the class itself, you should use the `static` keyword to define your `isIE` function as static.

```
var cookieExists = document.cookie.indexOf('ie11_cookie') >= 0;
class ieAlert {
  static isIE() {  
    return window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE|Trident)/);
  }
  // …
}
// …
if (ieAlert.isIE() && !cookieExists) {
  // …
}
```

Comment: I want to call the isIE function on an instance of the class, but don't know how exactly should I do it.

Comment: @user1941537 in this case you should define your method as `static`, because its definition does not depend on instances.

Comment: Thanks. But what would be the right syntax if I couldn't use static keyword.